# Shell script keeps making broken symbolic links

Tags: linux, shell-script, ln

I'm trying to manage my dot files inside a sub directory of $HOME and write a shell script that sets up symbolic links inside $HOME.

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in .cvsignore .gitconfig .npmrc .tmux.conf .zprofile .zshrc; do
    ln -s $i ~/$i
done
```

for some reason this script keeps producing broken symbolic links.

```
file {~/*,~/.*} | grep "broken symbolic link" | cut -d: -f1

/home/user/.cvsignore
/home/user/.gitconfig
/home/user/.npmrc
/home/user/.tmux.conf
/home/user/.zprofile
/home/user/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbolic links will be broken because they will look like

```
.cvsignore -> .cvsignore
```

etc.

When you create a symbolic link with

```
ln -s source target
```

then the `target` will be a symbolic link that points to `source` exactly the way you wrote it.

So, what's missing is the path to the source (here I'm using the `$PWD` variable which holds the absolute path to the current directory):

```
ln -s "$PWD/$i" "$HOME/$i"
```

---

Most of the time, one is located in the directory of the *target* when creating the link:

```
ln -s some/dir/where/the/file/is mylink
```

The link (the path that the link points to) should be absolute, or be relative to the location of the link.

Comment: Could you explain to me why ln can't figure out the target from the relative path name?

Comment: @Philippe The source path (the first argument to `ln`), if it's a relative path, needs to be relative to the target (the second argument).

Comment: Ok, I still don't understand why I can't use a relative target path and an absolute link name path

Comment: @Philippe You mean like in `ln -s "$PWD/file" ../../file`? That should not be a problem...

Comment: No, I meant the other way round.

Comment: @Philippe You can, but as I said, the path that the link points to has to be relative from the link.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66490/discussion-between-philippe-and-kusalananda).

Answer (score 0):

Are you standing in the same directory (ie. home of that user)? If yes, it would be linking to itself...

If you are in different directory, you'd need to specify full path to the target.

Comment: He's not. He is in a subdirectory (see first sentence).